# monkey patching at the npm package level?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, monkeypatching

I'd like to extend the npm package ["truffle"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/truffle), but currently in version 4 (and version 5), "truffle" doesn't have a plugin extension mechanism.

So the broad question is how to ["monkey patch"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) that. One possiblity would be to list the truffle package as a dependancy and then run some shell commands like ["patch"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_(Unix)) to modify truffle which is generally installed in `node_modules`.

Does npm have a way where I could run such shell commands after node dependencies are successfuly installed?

Any other suggestions? (Another method might be [monkey patching at the nodejs level](https://www.audero.it/blog/2016/12/05/monkey-patching-javascript/), but I think that will be more cumbersome.)

**EDIT**

The [postinstall](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#description) field of `scripts` in the `package.json` may be what I am looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the end we used [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package)

Comment: thank YOU for sharing your answer when you solved it. you helped me too.